# problem is about Eigen space, eigenvalues, eigenvectors and diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra

You are given a square matrix $A$ and that

• $\det (A) =  0$,
• The characteristic polynomial of $A$ has degree $5$,
• If we add $4$ to the diagonal of the matrix, the resulting matrix has $2$ pivots,
• The linearly independent vectors $u$ and $v$ satisfy the equation,
$A(u+v)= 7u+7v$

By using the information above determine answers to the following questions. Please write up your
solutions clearly and carefully, giving justification for each of your steps.

1. Can you identify any eigenvalues or eigenvectors in this problem?
2. What is the characteristic polynomial? How do you know?
3. Is the matrix $A$ diagonalizable? Why or why not? If it is diagonalizable, do you have enough
   information to determine $P$ or $D$ where $A= PDP^{-1}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given That The Matrix has Characteristics equation of degree 5 so Order of Matrix Is 5 .
Again  Given that when you add 4 to Diagonal element Then matrix has 2 pivots that is  rank of Matrix become 2 and Nulity is 3
I.e. $(A+4I)$ has Nulity 3  that Implies - 4 is an eigenvalue with GM 3 so AM of -4 is  greater than equal to 3 and we have 3 LI eigenvectors for -4

Again  $A(u+v) = 7u +7v$ where $u$ and $v$ are LI so $u$ and $v$ are 2 LI eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalue $7$

Hence We have Total 5 LI eigenvectors corresponding to $-4$ and $7$ .  So matrix is Diagonizable  hence AM= GM for each eigenvalues ..

So characteristics Polynomial is  $(x+4)^3(x-7)^2 =0$
Again We have nothing more than this So we can't find eigenvectors here. And So we can't find the Change of Basis matrix P .

And Diagonal matrix here is. diag$( -4, -4,-4,7,7)$

Hope this Was useful to You

Comment: welcome to MSE try to use JAX next time